# Highlighting Values In Column to Column Comparison using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to compare two columns in two separate sheets, each column contains data that is a string. My issue is that there is data in one column that is identical to the other in separate rows; therefore I have to check the entire column for the data before moving to the next. I am very inexperienced with VBA and am trying to make one portion of my job easier rather than comparing the columns by hand. I have piece wised the following code from research and trial and error. I am able to get the entire Column searched in my first Sheet, but only one value is being highlighted on the second sheet and then it is returning a value of "True" in the first column. I am unsure where I have gone wrong, any help is greatly appreciated!

```
     Sub Better_Work_This_Time()

     Dim FindString As String
     Dim Rng As Range
     ActiveCell = Sheets("Last Week").Range("A2").Activate
     FindString = ActiveCell

     Dim County As Integer

     Count = Cells.CurrentRegion.rows.Count

     For i = 2 To County
        If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
          With Sheets("Current Week").Range("A:A")
             Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
   
             If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                ActiveCell.Font.Color = vbBlue
             End If
        End With
      End If
      If IsEmpty(FindString) Then
         FindString = False
      End If

      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      i = i + 1
   Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? If you want to highlight cells, based on their content, conditional formatting is perfect for it. Obviously, when you use conditional formatting, the highlighting is done always, while using VBA, you can decide only to highlight when you decide. Is this the reason you're using VBA?

Comment: Suggest you add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (you should always use that).  It will make sure your varaible names are consistent (eg `County` vs `Count`)

Comment: You are getting True in first column because `ActiveCell = Sheets("Last Week").Range("A2").Activate` should just be `Sheets("Last Week").Range("A2").Activate`. And `FindString = ActiveCell` should be first line inside For/Next loop.

Answer (score 0):

Without using ActiveCell and using `Match` instead of `Find`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Does_Work_This_Time()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsLast As Worksheet, wsCurrent As Worksheet
    Dim FindString As String, ar, v
    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    ' put current week values into array
    Set wsCurrent = wb.Sheets("Current Week")
    With wsCurrent
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ar = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow).Value2
    End With
 
    ' scan last week matching current week
    Set wsLast = wb.Sheets("Last Week")
    With wsLast
        .Columns(1).Interior.Color = xlNone
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            FindString = Trim(.Cells(i, "A"))
            If Len(FindString) > 0 Then
                v = Application.Match(FindString, ar, 0)
                If IsError(v) Then
                    'no match
                ElseIf ar(v, 1) = FindString Then ' case match
                    .Cells(i, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(128, 255, 128) ' light green
                    n = n + 1
                End If
             End If
        Next

    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows matched"
End Sub
```